# How do I add jQuery click event to Django admin save and continue button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I am trying to add some elaborate javascript validation to a django admin form. When the user clicks any of the three types of save buttons (**save**, **save and continue**, or **save and add another**) my javascript will run. Part of what it does is make an ajax call to provide special checks before posting. When I capture the click event using jquery of the **add and continue** button, sometimes I stop the form being submitted and sometimes I allow it to be submitted. Sometimes, only warnings are thrown, rather than errors, and then the user can decide that the form should continue to be submitted.

When it is finally submitted in the end, it needs to be submitted using the process dictated by the button they clicked originally. I found that adding JS of `form.submit();` only submitted according to the **save** button, taking the user back to the model list, even if the user originally clicked the **save and continue** button.

I changed my JS from `form.submit();` to capture the button itself and to trigger a click of it that bypasses the validation if the user has chosen to disregard the warnings. But still it returns to the model list after saving, even if the clicked button was **save and continue**.

What is the Django admin doing client side to dictate a **save and continue** instead of a plain old **save** when the user pushes that button?

So here is the short, summarized version of my question...

**How can I, using Javascript (including jQuery), force a Django admin form submission that will:**

- **save and continue**
- **save and add another**

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. I had to create a hidden field with the name of the button that had been clicked and the value of the button that had been clicked and submit that field along with the form. Worked great!

---

EDIT (From 02/2020)

So I originally posted this Q&A years ago and haven't been working with Django for the last few months, but I see that someone wanted my code. Working from memory and a few pieces of code I still have around, it was something like this (which is untested)...

```
var frm = $('form');
var chosenBtn = frm.find('[name="_save"]');
var btns = frm.find('[name="_save"], [name="_addanother"], [name="_continue"]');
btns.unbind('click.btnAssign').bind('click.btnAssign', function(e)
{
    chosenBtn = $(this);
});
frm.unbind('submit.saveStuff').bind('submit.saveStuff', function(e)
{
    // Add your own validation here. If the validation fails, you can call:
    // e.preventDefault();
    // But if it works, no need for that line. If everything works...

    frm.append(
    [
        '<input type="hidden" name="',
        chosenBtn.attr('name'),
        '" value="',
        chosenBtn.attr('value'), // or maybe chosenBtn.text()
        '" />'
    ].join(''));
});
```

Comment: Please share your demo.